# Deploy SSRS R2 reports to non R2 server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, deployment, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have developed reports using SSRS 2008 R2 but now need to deploy to a server that is pre-R2 (SSRS 2008 SP2). Is this possible or will the server have to be upgraded?

I need to keep all current elements which include guages and bubble charts to name a few

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the target server version of the report in Business Intelligence Development Studio through the Report Project like below

1. Open up a report project containing all the reports in BIDS
2. Click "Project" on the top menu; then "*Project Name* Properties"
3. Under Configuration Properties -> General -> Deployment you can see at TargetServerVersion property.
4. Change this to SQL Server 2008
5. Click "OK"

This will allow you to deploy the reports through BIDS with the correct target version.  You may have to remove elements from the reports if they are not supported in 2008 (Maps and sparklines for example).

[image: TargetServerVersion]

Comment: Tried this however I have certain elements such as Bubble charts and guages that I cannot remove

Comment: @SelectDistinct: if you can't remove items that are 2008R2 specific, what should happen when you deploy to a 2008 server?

Comment: @Jamie F The deploy fails telling you that you are trying to deploy to a mismatched server. If you change the target server to match, it then fails telling you that you are using features that need R2.

Comment: @General, Yes, I understand. My question is directed at the OP: it sounds like they want features that are only in 2008R2, but want to deploy it to a 2008 server.

Comment: @JamieF certainly does sound like this. However I do not think this is possible.